# How to compare dates using Java

Tags: java, datetime

I have a date with the format 2012-02-02(yyyy-MM-dd).

For example if  todays date is 2012-02-02 i need to add one and a half days to it which would make it 2012-02-03 06:00:00.0.

And if i have a number of dates of the following format 2012-02-03 06:30:00.0(yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS.SSS) , i need to compare if all these dates are less than,greater than or equal to the date to which one and a half days were added above.

The comparison should also take care of the hours while comparing if the dates are less than,greater than or equal or equal to the other date and time.

How do i achieve the same.

Comment: You'd use the date manipulation (Calendar class) and comparison API. What have you tried?

Comment: Java has a `Calendar` class which can be used to compare dates/times: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: half a day is 12 hours, not 6. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well so i hope this will give you a clear idea. [Calendar Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and [SimpleDateFormat Documentaion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String aDateString = "2012-02-02";
Date date = sdf.parse(aDateString);
System.out.println("reference date:"+date);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 36);
System.out.println("added one and half days to reference date: "+cal.getTime());

String newDateString = "2012-02-03 06:30:00.0";
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
Date newDate = sdf.parse(newDateString);
System.out.println("new date to compare with reference date : "+newDate);

Calendar newCal = Calendar.getInstance();
newCal.setTime(newDate);

if(cal.after(newCal)){
    System.out.println("date is greater than reference that.");
}else if(cal.before(newCal)){
    System.out.println("date is lesser than reference that.");
}else{
    System.out.println("date is equal to reference that.");
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
reference date:Thu Feb 02 00:00:00 IST 2012
added one and half days to reference date: Fri Feb 03 12:00:00 IST 2012
new date to compare with reference date : Fri Feb 03 06:30:00 IST 2012
date is greater than reference that.
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple arithmetic approach (faster)

1. Parse the date using `SimpleDateFormat` that creates a `Date` object
2. Use `Date.getTime()` to return the UTC value in `long`
3. Convert 1 and half days to millis (1.5 Days = 129600000 Milliseconds) and add it to previous step
4. Use `>`, `<` and `==` or `after()`, `before()` and `equals()` if you want to use Date object itself

API approach (slower)

1. Use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)
2. `add(...)` method for adding 1 and half day
3. use `before()`, `after()` and `equals()` methods of Calendar

Comment: The simple arithmetic approach ignores time zones (well, uses UTC). So "plus 1.5 days" may lead to unexpected results in the face of daylight saving time. You may want to mention this in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Joda date time [API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

```
 String strDate="2012-02-02";
 DateTime dateTime=DateTime.parse(strDate);

 DateTime newDateTime=dateTime.plusHours(18); 
 System.out.println(dateTime);
 System.out.println(newDateTime);
```

Comment: Joda is an excellent library to use, but you don't *need* to.

Comment: The Java built-in Calendar is broken pretty badly.  Yes, you do.

Comment: I feel like I should point out that post Java 8, you should use the java.time.* stuff, since it's much better than Calendar and util date.

Answer (score 2):

- Use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert `String` to `Date`
- Set date to `Calendar` instance
- use `calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 36)`

**Also See**

- Joda Time API